# Create a layer, edit and save. Where are my features?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I created a layer (e.g. point) in QGIS with QgsVectorLayer from memory:

```
mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("point?crs=epsg:32630&field=id:string","TempFile","memory")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

and save it with writeAsVectorFormat:

```
error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(mem_layer, "C:\\Temp\\TempFile", "CP1250", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

This all works well, but **any features I add are not saved** (only after save, remove, load again).

Is there anyone who can help me?

---

Here some more info. It is a tiny plugin to create a predefined SHP file:

```
(fileNameText,fileNameBase) = QInputDialog.getText(None,"QGIS in LUPMIS","Enter name of new point file:")  
mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("point?crs=epsg:32630&field=id:string&field=caption:string&field=style:integer",fileNameText,"memory")  
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)  
temp1 = "C:\\LUPMIS\\LUPMISTemp\\" + fileNameText   
error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(mem_layer, temp1, "CP1250", None, "ESRI Shapefile")  
if error == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:  
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage("LUPMIS","Point layer saved as file " + fileNameText + ".shp",QgsMessageBar.INFO)
```

From here, users should continue with manual entry through toolbar icons: Toggle Editing - Save Layer Edits - Add Feature, etc

Comment: It seems they are saved, but not refreshed in QGIS. I have no access to qgis at the moment.

Comment: Might need to see some more code.  How are you adding features?